# automatically show target div

Tags: jquery, html, target

I know this is probably stupid but I have looked everywhere and cannot solve this. I am trying to make this http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentNavigator/index.html#slide-main automatically show. on a page load without a button click. I want to automatically load demo2 into an existing page but want it to show on page load. thank you all in advance

This is the css involved for the div tags:

```
 .cn-slide{
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
padding-top: 80px;
margin: 0 5%;
width: 90%;
opacity: 0;


}   
.cn-slide:target{
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO CHMedia. This site is for Question and Answers on **specific** code problems/issues, so your Q does not fit the needs. Post some code please. Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Add the code to the `onLoad()` event in addition to the `onClick()`

**Update:** Nevermind..

Answer (score 0):

Why Dont you try this:

UPDATED SOLUTION!

when the page loads this will send a redirect to include the #slide-main.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        location.href='index2.html#slide-main'
    });
</script>
```

after reading about this, it seems that it is not possible to trigger a click onload for this purpose. so this would be the only solution....i think !!

hope this helps

Comment: That doesnt work. neither one of them do nothing. It seems like I am running into this all day.

Comment: have you included jquery for the above?

Comment: ive downloaded the demo and tested a couple of things out and managed to get it to work.  Ive updated my answer. hope this helps

Comment: I did try to use a solution like that but the problem is that the div is located at the bottom of the page so it scrolls. If I could disable the scroll somehow that would work but I have had no luck disable the scroll. I even tried setting the opacity to 1 in the style sheet  for the #cs-slide to try to make it like the active state cssto no avail.

Comment: in that case, why dont you just put that sectio into an iframe at the bottom of the page and get the ifram to load the path index2.html#slide-main, this will keep everything as you want it and show onload. that should work

Comment: I also had that but the problem is I want to run prettybox and I cant make it pop the modal to the main window.

Comment: that will be because of the iframe i suspect, put it in an iframe, them break out of it when the page loads, this was just a quick browse but seems simialar: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/break-out-of-iframe/